# Google Drive - Change from 'Anyone with the link can view'

Tags: google-drive

I have a google drive folder with link sharing set to 'Anyone with the link can view', how can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on the folder
2. Press Share...
3. Click on "Anyone with the link can view" (this opens a dropdown menu)
4. Select the option you want
5. Press save